# How do I move the type value (log, detail, etc.) to the beginning of a postgres log?

Tags: logging, postgresql-9.6

I have the following line in my postgres.conf file:

```
log_line_prefix = '%t %h %d %u '
```

Along with these entries:

```
log_statement = 'all'
log_error_verbosity = default
```

Here's a bit of output in the log file:

```
2018-10-22 12:26:38 EDT 127.0.0.1 eccal eccal LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select * from country where country_code = $1
2018-10-22 12:26:38 EDT 127.0.0.1 eccal eccal DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'USA'
```

What I would like is to have the text 'LOG' and 'DETAIL' at the front of the line before the time.  I know that's not standard but I'm using FILEBEAT and I need to tell it what log lines to send to LOGSTASH.  I do that based on LOG, DETAIL, STATEMENT, etc. but if it's not at the beginning of the line it's a lot tougher to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `Filebeat` which log lines to send to LOGSTASH by using a regex pattern in `include_lines` setting in filebeat config.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.2/configuration-filebeat-options.html#include-lines

In your case it will be

`include_lines`: `['.*\sLOG.*','.*\sDETAIL.*']`